# System.OutOfMemoryException on gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a problem with my application.

First of all, sorry about my English, I'm from Chile and I'm still learning.

I have a method that gives an Excel with information from a db. Clients don't need to see the report on screen, they just need to download it from app.

This method calls a stored procedure, which gives too much data (about 600 columns and 20000 rows), so, when table is assigned to a GridView, on DataBind(), throws a `System.OutOfMemoryException`.

Is there any other way to load the GridView with data? I can't filter in query, or simplify it, because client needs every date from the report.
I'm using Visual Studio 2010, Framework 4.0, SQL Server 2008.

This is the method:

```
private void getsReport()
{
    string reportName = "Globarl_Report_" +     User.Identity.Name + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+".xls";
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SNAT"].ToString());
    DBCommandWrapper com = db.GetSqlStringCommandWrapper("usp_con_global_report);// sp that give report.

    com.CommandTimeout = 360;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    Page pagina = new Page();
    HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
    DataTable tabla = db.ExecuteDataSet(com).Tables[0]; ;
    GridView dg = new GridView();

    dg.EnableViewState = false;
    dg.DataSource = tabla;
    dg.DataBind();//THIS LINES THROWS EXCEPTION!!
    pagina.EnableEventValidation = false;
    pagina.DesignerInitialize();
    pagina.Controls.Add(form);
    form.Controls.Add(dg);
    pagina.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + nombreArchivo);
    Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default;
    Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

thanks for your help!!

Comment: Is there any reason why you are presenting 20.000 rows to the user? You should add search and filtering, as well as paging. And 600 columns??? No customer **need** 20.000 rows with 600 columns!

Comment: Would it be possible to modify `usp_con_global_report` to include a limit on the number of rows you return?

Comment: or lookup virtualization on google

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, right, my bad - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780657.aspx this explains the idea of virtualization (although it's not for asp.net)

Answer (score 0):

You should add a pager to your gridview.

Look here : [Paging and Sorting the GridView's Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading all data to grig to make it possible to export to Excel only?

In such case you can create csv file on server (by schedule or by client request dynamically) and put a link on page to download it.

Later it can be opened with Excel (or any other spreadsheet processor)